# Need to develop Android and iOS Apps which can support a module developed using Adobe Captivate

Tags: android, ios, html, flash, adobe-captivate

I have an e-learning module developed which was published in both formats i.e. **HTML5 and SWF** using **Adobe Captivate**. The module also have some interactive elements/actions which can be accessed on clicking them. Module is playing fine in web browser.

My requirement - I need to develop **Android and iOS native** applications which can utilise the above e-learning module.

I have searched online but couldn't find anything relevant on this topic, if anybody have implemented this then please guide further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Player file .swf file cannot be run on android, if you want to run then WebView is your best option.
For html5, if it is a full package containing javaScript then it is not possible as these things go with a package. Yes if your html5 file is online it can be run on WebView. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to open it as .zip, with most file types, like Excel or Word this works.